# Taking square root to quadruple precision

Tags: fortran, quadruple-precision

How can I do a square root for `Real(Real128)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just use the generic function `sqrt` and it will call the correct specific function, `qsqrt` (Not sure if that's a standard name. Both ifort and gfortran call it that). However, your compiler may not implement it yet. I know ifort does, but gfortran does not. And that applies to other intrinsic functions such as trig functions as well.

Also, quad precision operations are usually performed in software, so it's much slower.

Comment: To be clear: `gfortran` doesn't support `qsqrt` but `sqrt` works with `Real128`. The corresponding function is defined in libquadmath which might not be included in all compiler distributions. Normally, this library gets automatically linked to your program (You can check this with `ldd`).